# What's the difference between autovacuum general setting and autovacuum_enabled table setting in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

We have a database that is now on v15 PostgreSQL, but was recently migrated from v11, and before that v9.  I believe that many of the settings for our database were preserved from prior versions and may not be optimal/default for v15. Specifically, I'm trying to better understand the expected autovacuum behavior.

Based on other questions, I checked `show autovacuum` which returns `on`. This tells me that the database-wide autovacuum daemon is running.

And this query tells me the default autovacuum settings:

```
select *
from pg_settings 
where name like '%autovacuum%';
```

However, there are several tables where autovacuum does not seem to be running or never has been run.  I suspect this is because autovacuum was never specifically enabled for these tables in the prior versions of PostgreSQL that they were created in and transferred from.  i.e., the `reloptions` column returned from the following query is NULL for tables where autovacuum doesn't run and is set to `{autovacuum_enabled=true}` for tables where autovacuum does run:

```
select pg_namespace.nspname, relname, reloptions
from pg_class
join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
where relname like 'sometablename%' and pg_namespace.nspname = 'someschemaname';
```

Is this an accurate understanding of the reloptions/autovacuum_enabled behavior?

I understand that I can run the following query to enable autovacuum on a specific table:

`ALTER TABLE schemaname.tablename SET (autovacuum_enabled = true);`

However, what do I need to consider before enabling autovaccuum on a table?

- Are any tables 'too small' (i.e., why bother?)
- Can tables be 'too big' (i.e., if autovacuum runs on a very large table can the server run out of space, and/or will DB performance suffer?)
- If a table is created and written to but then never updated, does enabling autovacuum on this table benefit me at all?
- If a table is written to regularly during the day but idle at night, can I schedule autovacuum to run on this table during specific times of day or days of week?  How?

Answer (score 1):

The storage option `autovacuum_enabled` defaults to `on`, so all your tables should get autovacuumed whenever they need it. Autovacuum should **always** be enabled on **all tables**. Perhaps your tables don't get vacuumed because they don't need it. Look for the number of dead tuples in `pg_stat_user_tables`.

Comment: So even when the `reloptions` column returned from the query is NULL for a particular table, autovacuum is still run on that table?

Comment: Yes, autovacuum is enabled by default.